# $x.contains doesn't work with "`n"

Tags: powershell, match, special-characters, contains

If I generate a text file with `Out-File` with an `` `n `` in it and I want to proof if there is a `` `n ``, the result is always FALSE.

Here is the code:

```
$x="c:\temp\test.txt"
"`n" | Out-File $x
$x.contains("`n") #False
```

or

```
$x -contains "`n" #False
```

or

```
$x -match "`n" #False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are testing *the filename* instead of the content.

Comment: FYI `-Contains` is used to test if an array contains an object and won't work with strings. You need to use `-Like` for that, eg: `if ($string -like "*blah*") { #do stuff }`

Answer (score 2):

`$x` is a string with a value of `c:\temp\test.txt` - since there are no line-breaks in the string `c:\temp\test.txt`, `Contains()` returns `$false`.

To see if there are any line-breaks in the file, retrieve the contents of it as one big multiline string with `Get-Content -Raw`:

```
(Get-Content $x -Raw).Contains("`n")
```

Comment: Hello again,
thank you for all of the answers!

@Matthias: I've tried your command, but I've got an error message. The Parameter -Raw is unknown.